# Start function when condition is met (has class in-view)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, class, animation

I have this animation code:

```
 var setInter = null
 function startAnimation() {
     var frames = document.getElementById("animation").children;
     var frameCount = frames.length;
     var i = 0;
     setInter = setInterval(function () {
         frames[i % frameCount].style.display = "none";
         frames[++i % frameCount].style.display = "block";
         if(i>=18){ 
             clearInterval(setInter);
         }
     }, 100);
 }
```

This runs an animation by frames. When the condition is met, 19 frames, the animations stops.

I want to start this function only when `#animation` has class "in-view". I already got that clear, when I scroll to that div, it gets the class "in-view", but I can't get the function to only start when the condition is met, it only runs onload.

Any ideas? Javascript is not my strong suit :).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **jQuery's** `.hasClass()` :

```
if($('#animation').hasClass('in-view')){
   startAnimation();
}
```